# Proof by induction - Fibonacci

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have a sequence defined as:

$u_1 = 1$

$u_2 = 1$

$u_{k+1} = u_{k-1} + u_k$

Which gives: $$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8\ldots$$

I need to prove for $n \geqslant 2$ that:

$$u_n^2 = u_{n-1}\cdot u_{n+1} + (-1)^{n-1}$$

So for the base case:

$$1^2 = 1*2 + (-1)^1$$
$$1^2 = 1$$

Then for the induction hypothesis I have:

$$u^2_{k} = u_{k-1}\cdot u_{k+1} + (-1)^{k-1}$$

So I need to show that 
$${u^2_{k+1}} = u_{k}\cdot u_{k+2} + (-1)^{k}$$

I started by multiplying the induction hypothesis by $-1$

$$u_{k-1}\cdot u_{k+1} - u^2_{k} = (-1)^k$$

but I got stuck at this point, have I structured this in the wrong way?

**EDIT**:Others have mentioned the Cassini and Catalan identities, but I wanted to do this without resorting to matrices (I don't know if it's possible)

Comment: Maybe as a first step, try to eliminate the $u_{k-1}$ from the inductive hypothesis and see where that leads.

Comment: My favorite proof is the matrix one. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities

Comment: See this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cassini%27s_Identity#Basis_for_the_Induction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let, ${u_n}^2-{u_{n-1}}{u_{n+1}}=(-1)^{n-1}$.

Then,

$${u_{n+1}}^2-{u_{n}}{u_{n+2}}={u_{n+1}}^2-{u_{n}}(u_{n+1}+u_{n})$$

$$={u_{n+1}}(u_{n+1}-u_{n})-{u_n}^2={u_{n+1}}u_{n-1}-{u_n}^2=(-1)(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{(n+1)-1}$$

And this way, it is proved

Comment: shouldn't you have a $u_{n+2}$ somewhere?

Comment: That is there, I have written at the start of the induction process.